# What is the size of pointer to an array of type int?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int arr[] = {10,20,30,40};
    int* ptr = arr;
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(arr));
    printf("%d",sizeof(ptr));
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
16
4
```

size of pointer in C is 4. 'arr' is also a pointer to an integer but its size comes out to be 16, which is product of size of one element and number of elements.
 On the other hand if I store the same pointer into another pointer variable then its size becomes 4. This is very confusing. The same thing happens if I try to send arr as an argument to a function and then print the size of arr in that function. How does C handle a pointer to an array?

Comment: Here is a good explanation of the difference between a pointer and an array [Is array name a pointer in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c)

Comment: Also see the comp.lang.c [FAQ 7.28 "Why doesn't sizeof tell me the size of the block of memory pointed to by a pointer?"](http://c-faq.com/malloc/sizeof.html)

Comment: thanks @KlasLindbäck above examples washed all my misconceptions..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 'arr' is also a pointer to integer

No, it's not. `arr` is an array. The size of an array is the size of an element times the number of elements. If it were a pointer, it's size would be the same as any other pointer.

> How does C handles pointer of array?

C handles pointers to arrays the same way it handles all other pointers. However there are no pointers to arrays in your code, only a pointer to int (`ptr`).

Answer (score 3):

A pointer is just a memory address, therefore on 32-bit systems it is always 4 bytes. Depending on the environment it is 4 or 8 bytes on 64-bit systems.

There is no real confusion in your example. `arr` is an array of 4 32-bit integers, therefore 16 bytes. It is 'handled', or 'passed around', as a pointer to the first int, an `int*`, which is why you can copy it to other variables of that type, either explicitly or as a parameter. At which time there is no longer a relationship to the original array, and it is just a pointer - 4 bytes on your system.

The best way to look at it is that there is an implicit conversion possible from `int[]` to `int*`, like there is from `char` to `int`.

Answer (score 1):

- When you do `sizeof(arr)` you will get the size of array which is `number of elements * size of int`.
- When you do `sizeof(ptr)` you will get the size of pointer which is `size of int`.

> This is very confusing. The same thing happens if I try to send arr as an argument to a function and then print the size of arr in that function.

When you send the array like this `foo(arr)`, you are actually sending the base address of `arr`. And when we pass address of a variable to a function, it will store the address in a pointer. So again if you try to get the size of `arr` you'll get the size of pointer.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` only works to find the length of the array if you apply it to the original array.

```
int a[5]; //real array. NOT a pointer
sizeof(a); // :)
```

However, by the time the array decays into a pointer, sizeof will give the size of the pointer and not of the array.

```
int a[5];
int * p = a; // assigning address of the array to pointer
sizeof(p); // :(
```

It will return always 4 bytes on 32-bit system and 8 bytes on 64-bit system!

Arrays decaying into pointers when they are passed to a function and continuing to keep the array length in the type system.

When you pass an array to a function it decays to pointer. So the `sizeof` function will return the size of `int *`

So when you pass the array to the function you need to pass the Number of elements also-

```
void function (size_t sz, int *arr) { ... }
:
{
    int x[20];
    function (sizeof(x)/sizeof(*x), x);
}
```